# Background image in a polygon / CountryData

Tags: graphics, curated-data, textures

Is it possible to use a background image in a polygon without rasterizing the polygon?

I tried with textures, but they seem to be viable only for simple polygons.

I want to put a flag as the background of the polygon that represents a country shape. I can do this for one country by rasterizing the polygon:

```
ImageAdd[
    Graphics[CountryData["Monaco", "Polygon"]], 
    CountryData["Monaco", "Flag"]
]
```

[image: monaco]

But by rasterizing the polygon, I make it difficult to apply this procedure to several neigboring countries and assemble them together.

I would like to put each country flag in the background of, for example:

```
Graphics[
    {EdgeForm[White], 
     CountryData[#, "Polygon"] & /@ {"Venezuela", "Colombia"}}]
```

[image: colombia and venezuela]

---

### Solution

After seeing cormullion answer, I was able to do what I wanted:

```
Graphics[
 {EdgeForm[Black],
  {{Texture[ImageReflect[CountryData[#, "Flag"], Top -> Right]], 
    CountryData[#, "Polygon"] /. 
      {Polygon[a_] :> Polygon[First[a], VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
       Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose[First[CountryData[#, "Coordinates"]]]]]}} & /@ 
CountryData["SouthAmerica"]}}]
```

[image: southamerica]

The key part is the use of Rescale[].

Comment: I wish *Mathematica* had more advanced vector-graphics and layering;  this is so simple in a drawing program.  A *good* solution would preserve everything as vector with no rasterized textures, but I don't think it can be done in a general way. -- *edit* I didn't notice that the Flag data is already raster.  I guess Texture makes the most sense in that case.

Comment: You may find `ImagePad` useful if you want small flags inside country borders

Comment: One caveat: This texture-based approach leads to a graphic that cannot be exported to PDF (on Macs, at least). This seems worth mentioning since you specifically asked for a method preserving the vector character of the borders.  Just in case anyone encounters this, a workaround for this problem is to export to svg first, and then use Inkscape to convert to PDF.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This example is from the documentation for `Texture` in Mathematica version 8:

```
With[{vc = 
 Transpose[
  Rescale /@ Transpose[First[CountryData[#, "Coordinates"]]]]}, 
Show[CountryData[#, "Shape"], 
 ImageSize -> {{100}, {100}}] /. {RGBColor[__] :> 
  Texture[ImageReflect[Image[CountryData[#, "Flag"]], 
    Top -> Right]], 
 Polygon[a_] :> 
  Polygon[First[a], VertexTextureCoordinates -> vc]}] & /@ 
CountryData["SouthAmerica"]
```

but I don't know whether it does what you need. Still, it looks pretty.

[image: flags]

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], {{Texture[Image[CountryData[#, "Flag"]]], 
  Polygon[First@First[CountryData[#, "Polygon"]], 
   VertexTextureCoordinates ->Transpose[
     Rescale /@ Transpose[First@First[CountryData[#, 
         "Polygon"]]]]]}} & /@ {"Venezuela", "Colombia"}}]
```

which gives

[image: maps and flags]

Comment: Note that your country coordinates are somewhat rotated (transposed).

Comment: Thank you @Artes. I need to change `Coordinates` to `Polygon` in the first argument of `Polygon`.

Comment: Now, country polygons are correctly oriented while flags are rotated.

Comment: @Artes, thank you again. Just noticed, that OP alrady put together the solution  more than an hour ago.

Answer (score 2):

For coastal countries with a lot of islands, `CountryData[tag,"Polygon"]` gives something of the form `Polygon[{island1, island2, island3,...}]`, where `island1` and the like is another list of latitudes and longitudes.

The case is simpler for inland countries. `CountryData[tag,"Polygon"]` gives `Polygon[{island1}]`, where island1 is simply the mainland, and is itself a list of latitudes and longitudes.

An example can be given using UK and Venezuela:

```
Table[Length /@ First[CountryData[country, "Polygon"]], {country, {"UnitedKingdom", "Venezuela"}}]
```

The result is:

```
{{20, 25, 31, 54, 52, 63, 141, 195, 1927}, {491}}
```

which means that UK is made up of 9 polygons/islands, and Venezuela only 1.

To fill a country's land with its own flag, we must be careful to apply the flag texture to all the islands. The important thing is to treat each island of a country one by one.

To apply a texture to any polygon, we must first come up with a function that can yield the correct `VertexTextureCoordinates`. For example:

```
countryRescale1[polygon_] := (Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose[First[polygon]]])
```

The function accepts as argument a polygon of an island of a country, which is of the form `Polygon[{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}}]`. We obtain the list of coordinates with `First[]`.

We apply transpose to the list of coordinates `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}}`, so that we group all the x's together, and y's together: `{{x1, x2, x3, ...}, {y1, y2, y3, ...}}`. We apply to it `Rescale[]`, so that x's and y's are both rescaled from 0 to 1 separately. Then apply transpose to group them back into `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}}`, where `x` and `y` is now in `[0,1]`.

Then we can overlay the flag onto a country. Let's use Hong Kong (though not a country, but it has many islands) as an example. The important thing is to treat each island of a country one by one.

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Texture[CountryData["HongKong", "Flag"]], 
  Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> countryRescale1[Polygon[#]]] & /@
  First[CountryData["HongKong", "Polygon"]]}]
```

We map the pure function `Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> countryRescale1[Polygon[#]]]&` to the expression `First[CountryData["HongKong", "Polygon"]]`, which in itself is a list of islands { **{**{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ..., {xn,yn}**}**, **{**{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...**}**, ... }.

So it's just like:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Texture[CountryData["HongKong", "Flag"]],
  {Polygon[], Polygon[], Polygon[] ... }]
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Hong Kong with the islands]

For Argentina, the island province Tierra del Fuego (the bottom right triangular piece of land) is also treated with the flag:

[image: Argentina with the island]

The final thing left to do is to apply this to all countries to make a world flag map:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Table[{Texture[CountryData[c, "Flag"]], 
  Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> countryRescale1[Polygon[#]]] & /@  
  First[CountryData[c, "FullPolygon"]]}, {c, CountryData[]}]}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

For better flags, one can refer to this post: [Why do some CountryData flags render at low resolution?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11061/why-do-some-countrydata-flags-render-at-low-resolution)

Comment: I have used the better flags, 500px ones from [Why do some CountryData flags render at low resolution?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11061/why-do-some-countrydata-flags-render-at-low-resolution) to create a world flag map. What is the right way to export it so that I can zoom in and see even Hong Kong? Should I use 200px, 500px, or 1000px for the flags?

Comment: What do you think of this piece of code `Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black],{Texture[CountryData[#1,"Flag"]],Polygon[#,VertexTextureCoordinates->countryRescale1[Polygon[#]]]&/@First[CountryData[#1,"FullPolygon"]]}&/@CountryData[]},ImageSize->200]` as compared to the one using `Table[]`?