# Weather Maps with Mathematica

Tags: visualization, curated-data

I've been trying to set up a weather map with Mathematica similar to what NOAA publishes in their website.

[image]

So far I've been successful to bring the data over and extend it across the whole picture frame.

```
           weatherMap[region_, property_] := 
         Module[{polygon, coord, minX, maxX, minY, maxY, data, deltaX, deltaY},

          polygon = CountryData[region, "Polygon"];
          coord = Cases[CountryData[region, "Coordinates"], {_, _}, Infinity];
          minX = Floor@Min[coord[[All, 2]]];
          maxX = Ceiling@Max[coord[[All, 2]]];
          minY = Floor@Min[coord[[All, 1]]];
          maxY = Ceiling@Max[coord[[All, 1]]];
          deltaX = (maxX - minX)/25;
          deltaY = (maxY - minY)/25;
          data = DeleteCases[
            Flatten[Table[{x, y, WeatherData[{y, x}, property]}, {x, minX, 
               maxX, deltaX}, {y, minY, maxY, deltaY}], 1], {x_, 
             y_, _Missing}];
          Show[Graphics[{Opacity[0], polygon}], 
           ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> 10, 
            ColorFunction -> "Temperature", InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
            PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Above], 
            PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
           Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Opacity[0.01], GrayLevel[.1]], 
             polygon}]]]
   weatherMap["USA", "Temperature"]
```

[image]

What would be the best way to limit the contour temperature graphic to within the frame of the given polygon?

Comment: "Pato Criollo" ... ha! Nice username :)

Comment: If you want a more detailed map of the USA, this isn't built-in, but there is some data you can use [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/09/24/analyzing-us-2008-elections-with-mathematica/).

Comment: Related, if not duplicate:  [(528)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/528/121), [(2009)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2009/121), [(3723)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3723/121)

Comment: Marginally related, and I may be remembering wrong, but ExampleData[], alone, just by itself, by default, brings up a weather map.

Comment: Is it possible that a Wolfram Blog entry from a few years ago has pointers you can use?  The link is http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/01/13/visualizing-weather-patterns-in-mathematica-7/

Comment: @dwa, sadly the supporting notebook for that blog entry seems to be gone... (luckily, it can still be obtained from the Wayback Machine.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One key function you might need is the (undocumented) function `` Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[] ``, which tests if a point is inside a given polygon. With it, and a few other tweaks, here's my version of `weatherMap[]`:

```
weatherMap[region_String, property_String, res_Integer: 25, opts___] :=
  Module[{fmin, cmax, coords, pts, minLong, maxLong, minLat, maxLat,
          deltaLong, deltaLat, data},
  fmin = Composition[Floor, Min]; cmax = Composition[Ceiling, Max];
  coords = CountryData[region, "Coordinates"] /. v_?VectorQ :> Reverse[v];
  pts = Flatten[coords, 1];
  {minLong, maxLong} = Through[{fmin, cmax}[pts[[All, 1]]]];
  {minLat, maxLat} = Through[{fmin, cmax}[pts[[All, 2]]]];
  {deltaLong, deltaLat} = {maxLong - minLong, maxLat - minLat}/res;
  data = Table[WeatherData[{lat, long}, property],
               {long, minLong, maxLong, deltaLong}, {lat, minLat, maxLat, deltaLat}];
  ListContourPlot[data, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
                  DataRange -> {{minLong, maxLong}, {minLat, maxLat}},
                  Epilog -> {Directive[EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None]], Polygon[coords]},
                  opts, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", Contours -> 10,
                  InterpolationOrder -> 3, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
                  RegionFunction -> (Or @@ Map[Function[polys,
                  Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[polys, {#1, #2}]], coords] &)]]
```

(Not having *Mathematica* 9, I had to omit the option `PlotLegends`; you can add it back yourself.)

Test:

```
weatherMap["USA", "Temperature"]
```

[image: heat map for USA]

I should note that I thought it best not to delete `Missing[]` entries, since `ListContourPlot[]` is certainly able to cope with them (note the holes in the picture), and I feel it is dishonest to pretend that data exists in regions where there is actually none.

---

If you want your weather maps to be a bit more accurate, and you don't mind a bit of a wait (`WeatherData[]` is, after all, rather slow), you can use a `DensityPlot[]` (similar to what Mark suggested), and let the internal adaptive sampling algorithms do the sampling for you, instead of having to sample at equispaced longitudes/latitudes, and potentially missing data. With this in mind, here is a shorter (but slower) implementation of `weatherMap[]`:

```
weatherMap[region_String, property_String, opts___] := 
 Module[{coords, minLong, maxLong, minLat, maxLat},

        coords = CountryData[region, "Coordinates"] /. v_?VectorQ :> Reverse[v];
        If[VectorQ[CountryData[region, "Countries"], TrueQ], coords = Flatten[coords, 1]];
        {{minLong, maxLong}, {minLat, maxLat}} = PlotRange[Graphics[Polygon /@ coords]];

        DensityPlot[WeatherData[{lat, long}, property],
                    {long, minLong, maxLong}, {lat, minLat, maxLat},
                    AspectRatio -> Automatic, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, opts,
                    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thickness[Medium], Black],
                    ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", MaxRecursion -> 1,
                    Mesh -> 10, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
                    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
                    Or @@ (Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[#, {x, y}] & /@ coords)]]]
```

Some new features you might notice include the (undocumented) use of `PlotRange[]` to reckon out appropriate bounds for the data to be plotted, and the use of `MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}` so that one could still see the contours where `property` is constant.

Here again is the temperature map for the United States:

```
weatherMap["USA", "Temperature"]
```

[image: USA temperature map with finer sampling]

The color function can be easily changed, of course:

```
weatherMap["USA", "Temperature", ColorFunction -> "LightTemperatureMap"]
```

[image: USA temperature map with finer sampling, different color scheme]

Here's a demonstration of `weatherMap[]` on a collection of countries, showing its handling of noncontiguous land masses:

```
weatherMap["WesternEurope", "Temperature"]
```

[image: temperature map for Western Europe]

Finally, to demonstrate the use of a "rainbow" map, here's a temperature map of Malaysia:

```
(* "jet" colormap *)
jet[u_?NumericQ] :=
        Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan}, {13/21, Yellow},
               {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, u] /; 0 <= u <= 1

weatherMap["Malaysia", "Temperature", ColorFunction -> jet]
```

[image: Malaysian temperature map, jet color scheme]

(On the other hand, there are a number of reasons to avoid rainbow-like color maps for applications like these; see e.g. [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/6.736450) and [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MCG.2007.323435).)

Comment: " it is dishonest to pretend that data exists in regions where there is actually none." Isn't that just what we'd usually call *interpolation*?

Comment: @Sjoerd, sure, but if there are no measurements within a large swath of the region being considered, interpolation isn't exactly honest; interpolation might say a patch the size of Detroit is currently sunny if the surrounding counties are sunny, even though there is in fact a nice spell of sleet currently happening.

Comment: Dear J. M.,There are some issues with the code when trying to run it against a group of countries, such as weatherMap["WesternEurope","Temperature"]. Any ideas on how to solve it?  Error message Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ::invpoly: -- Message text not found -- (Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[{{{1.72194,42.5012},{1.70363,42.4898},{1.67035,42.5041},{1.65746,42.4687},{1.59763,42.4676},{1.58084,42.45},<<16>>,{1.5784,42.6461},{1.60504,42.6231},{1.74013,42.6129},{1.73606,42.5875},{1.79514,42.5821},{1.73871,42.5655}}},<<1>>])

Comment: @Zviovich, hopefully fixed in this version.

Answer (score 15):

If you want it to look like your NOAA example, that's not a `ContourPlot[]`.  It's a `DensityPlot[]` using a modified `Hue[]` function for the `ColorFunction`.  E.g. something like:

```
Show[ListDensityPlot[{#4, #3, #5} & @@@ Select[maxt, #[[5]] < 9999 &],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x}, Hue[Clip[(100 - x)/60, {0, 1}]]], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic], 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[0], 
   CountryData["UnitedStates", "Polygon"]}]]
```

[image: result]

See the other answer for a polygon solution.

*Update:*

@0x4A4D asked how to get `maxt`.  I downloaded the data from NOAA, [ds.maxt.bin](http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/SL.us008001/ST.opnl/DF.gr2/DC.ndfd/AR.conus/VP.001-003/ds.maxt.bin), which is in GRIB2 format.  Unfortunately Mathematica 9's `Import[]` knows about GRIB, but not GRIB2.  So I also [downloaded](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/degrib/download.php), compiled, and ran code to translate GRIB2 into CSV.  I picked one of the three data sets generated, imported that, and assigned it to `maxt`.