# How to texturize a Disk/Circle/Rectangle?

Tags: graphics, textures

The documentation for [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html) states that "***other filled objects***" can be texturized:

> `Texture[obj]` is a graphics directive that specifies that *obj* should be
>   used as a texture on faces of polygons and other filled graphics
>   objects.

And also:

> Texture can be used in FaceForm to texture front and back faces
>   differently.

Though I fail to apply a simple texture to any of the following objects. It seems like that "other filled objects" only include `Polygon`s and `FilledPolygon`s, and `FaceForm` does not work with those.

```
img = Rasterize@
   DensityPlot[Sin@x Sin@y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Frame -> None, 
    ImageSize -> 100, PlotRangePadding -> 0];
{
 Graphics[{Texture@img, Disk[]}],
 Graphics[{FaceForm@Texture@img, Disk[]}],
 Graphics[{Texture@img, Rectangle[]}],
 Graphics[{FaceForm@Texture@img, Rectangle[]}],

 (* Only this one works *)
 Graphics[{Texture@img, 
   Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}],
 Graphics[{FaceForm@Texture@img, 
   Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
 }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit:**

It turns out that "Applying `Texture` to a disk directly isn't possible" (according to [Heike](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Nov/msg00582.html), thanks [s.s.o.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7671/89) for the link). This unfortunately means that:

1. the official documentation of `Texture` is wrong (or at least is misleading, as [graphics objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphicsObjects.html) usually include primitives);
2. either `Texture` is not fully integrated with the system, as it is not  applicable for such primitives as a `Rectangle`, which seems to be just a very specific `Polygon`; or `Rectangle` is something else and is defined some other way at the lowest level than a `Polygon` (maybe it is some OS-dependent object).

Frankly, it is quite hard to imagine what kept developers to include this functionality, but I must assume they had a good reason.

Comment: I imagine that you know how to do this with `ParametricPlot` and `PlotStyle` as in the documentation for `ParametricPlot`?

Comment: @Mark: But any `Plot` is not a graphics primitive, is it? (btw, are you referring to `RegionPlot`?) I would like to texturize primitives, if possible. I am also aware of these threads: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2009/89) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1332/89).

Comment: I don't think you can `Texture` primitives like `Disk[]`, `Sphere[]`, etc

Comment: @Istvan Right. I guess I meant to say that I suspect that you know how to achieve the basic effect with `ParametricPlot`, not how to produce the exact primitives. Sometimes an alternative approach is of interest but, since you're a regular, I didn't think I'd bother typing up a response based on that.

Comment: @Mark: As always, I am interested in any bypass solution, please post yours if it hasn't been posted anywhere else!

Comment: @Istvan  Done...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I noticed an example in the document of `Texture` which used the alpha channel. So I think a disk-shape primitive may be simulated to a limited degree by mapping the image `img`, which has been set to 100% transparent outside of the circle, onto a rectangle-shape `Polygon`.

My code:

```
img = Rasterize[
                DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y],
                            {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},
                            ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow",
                            Frame -> None, ImageSize -> 100, PlotRangePadding -> 0
              ]];

imgdim = ImageDimensions[img]

alphamask = Array[
                  If[
                     Norm[{#1, #2} - imgdim/2] < imgdim[[1]]/2,
                     1,0]&,
                  imgdim];

alphaimg = MapThread[Append, {img // ImageData, alphamask}, 2];

Graphics[{
          Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}} + .3],
          Texture[alphaimg],
          Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
                  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
                 ],
          Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, .5]
         }]
```

which gives result like this:

[image: result graph]

Comment: Clever! I always forget that such problems can be solved by image processing tricks.

Comment: @IstvánZachar but it's less effective than your fallback method, and the boundary is ugly OTL

Comment: Definitely the best method (+1).

Answer (score 8):

Like RM, I've not been able to texture a `Disk` primitive.  We can create a textured disk using `ParametricPlot`, however.

```
ParametricPlot[{r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  Mesh -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> False,
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], 
   Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "LightCherry"}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: You will also want to look into the option `TextureCoordinateFunction`; for instance, compare Mark's plot with `ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "LightCherry"}]]}, TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #3} &)]`.

Comment: Yes - In fact, I lifted that code right out of the documentation for `TextureCoordinateFunction`.

Comment: @J.M. In version 10.1.0 under Windows I am getting `ParametricPlot::optx: "Unknown option TextureCoordinateFun‌​ction->({#4,#3}&) in ParametricPlot"` Has this Option been removed since you wrote that comment?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, how very odd; I just tested it in versions 8.0.4, 10.4.1, and 11, and it proceeds as expected in all three.

Comment: @J.M. It's too late in my day for me to check now, but I'll have to make sure I didn't cause the problem myself with some modification I forgot about.

Answer (score 5):

My fallback method for the moment is the following: approximate a circle with a polygon, fill the latter with the texture and finally conceal the angular edge with an overlaid `Circle`. If the whole image is small, the number of nodes of the polygon can be further reduced. One annoying sideeffect is though that the `Circle` is not antialiased...

```
img = Rasterize@
   DensityPlot[Sin@x Sin@y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Frame -> None, 
    ImageSize -> 200, PlotRangePadding -> 0];
coord = Block[{n = 100}, 
   Table[{Cos[2 \[Pi] k/n], Sin[2 \[Pi] k/n]}, {k, 0, n - 1}]];
Graphics[{Texture@img, EdgeForm@None, 
  Polygon[coord, VertexTextureCoordinates -> (coord/2 + .5)], Black, 
  Thick, Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 200, Background -> GrayLevel@.9]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can replace `Circle[]` with `Style[Circle[], Antialiasing -> True]` to get the circle antialiased. (+1)

Comment: @kguler: Strangely, this does not work on my end, no matter how hard I try.

Comment: Strange... perhaps os/version/hardware differences?  Suggestion was from the docs on `Antialiasing`.

Comment: @kguler: I have no idea, I probably had messed up something myself, but I gave up on this for now.

Answer (score 5):

*Mathematica* 10 introduced [Regions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DerivedRegions.html) which make this kind of operation much easier.

```
img = Rasterize@
   DensityPlot[Sin@x Sin@y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Frame -> None, ImageSize -> 100, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0];

RegionPlot[
  RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, {2, 2}], Disk[{0, 0}, {3.5, 0.7}]]
  , PlotStyle -> Texture[img]
][[{1}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As of version 12.1, we can use (yet undocumented) `SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[img]]` to texturize 2D primitives such as `Disk`, `Rectangle` as well as 3D primitives like `Sphere`, `Tube` etc.

```
lena = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
mandrill = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];

Graphics[{SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[ImageMultiply[lena, Green]]], 
  Disk[], 
  SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[mandrill]], 
  Rectangle[{2, -3/2}, {4, 1/2}], 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ RegionUnion[Disk[{1, 1}], Rectangle[{3/2, 1}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you click the disk and check Drawing tools from the menu there is only color fill options no texture options available. Also see Heike's related answers: [in math group](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Nov/msg00582.html) or [mathematica group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/1b79OQTMZ1s/KH8nWRboFxoJ) mainly she states "Applying Texture to a disk directly isn't possible, but you could for example use RegionPlot with the TextureCoordinateFunction option, e.g"

```
img = Rasterize@
   DensityPlot[Sin@x Sin@y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Frame -> None, 
    ImageSize -> 100, PlotRangePadding -> 0];

RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Texture[img]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an extension of Silvia's method of setting an alpha channel in the texture. The alpha mask is obtained directly from the shape using `Rasterize`, allowing the code to work with ellipses, rectangles, etc.

```
img = Rasterize@
   DensityPlot[Sin@x Sin@y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Frame -> None, 
    ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> 0];

texturedShape[img_, shape_] := Module[{g, p, ar, i},
  g = Graphics[shape, PlotRangePadding -> 0];
  p = Polygon[
    AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange][[1, 
       2]] /. {{l_, r_}, {b_, t_}} :> {{l, b}, {l, t}, {r, t}, {r, 
        b}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 
       0}}];
  ar = AbsoluteOptions[g, AspectRatio][[1, 2]];
  i = SetAlphaChannel[img, 
    ColorNegate@Rasterize[g, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img]];
  i = ImageCrop[i, 
    Round[If[ar > 1, {1/ar, 1}, {1, ar}] ImageDimensions@img]];
  {Texture[ImageData@i], p}]
```

The `Rasterize` gets its `ImageDimensions` from the original texture image, so I've increased the size of that to 300 to get cleaner edges.

Examples:

```
Graphics[{texturedShape[img,Disk[{0,0},2]],Red,Disk[{0,1},1]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{texturedShape[img,Disk[{0,0},{2,1}]],Red,Disk[{0,1},1]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{Red,Disk[{0,0},0.5],texturedShape[img,Rectangle[]]}]
```

[image]