# Gradient/ColorFunction in Disk with transparent background

Tags: graphics, color

My goal is to make an iOS-like enable/disable switch like this:

[image: iOS sliders]

I use a `LocatorPane` for the slider with so-called "jumps" to only make two settings possible:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{-.5, -.5}, {1.5, .5}]}],
            {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}},
            Appearance -> ImageResize[Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]},
                                               Background -> None], Scaled[.25]]]
```

Now, I want make the 'slider' better looking by adding a gradient to it but i cannot make it work. `ColorFunction` (probably the only way to add gradients in *Mathematica*) seems not available to `Disk`.
I tried using Heike's solution for gradients in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7657), but pasting the graphics from her function into my code does not work: the size of these graphics is way too large and rescaling it (using `ImageResize`) adds a white background which I cannot remove.
I tried making a disk with a gradient myself using `Raster` and `ImageAdd`, but here the same problem of a none-removable background occurs again:

```
ImageAdd[
Graphics[Raster[Table[i, {i, 100}, {j, 200}],
         {Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]}, {1, 100}, ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"]],
Graphics[Disk[]]]
```

Can anyone give some tips about how to add gradients to disks?

Comment: Hmmm... possibly a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7657/5. Silvia's answer is probably what you're looking for. In short, generate the gradient using any of the plotting functions, set an alpha channel and clip it to a disk region and texturize a polygon with that.

Comment: Texture was an option i did not think of, clever! For this purpose the answer for cormullion does the trick.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the edit. Had a hard time formatting the code in a nice way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems a bit clumsy, but how about this:

```
shiny[z_] := GrayLevel[1 - z/4];

gradient = 
  Image[DensityPlot[y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> None, ColorFunction -> shiny, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> True]];
diskAlpha = 
  Image[Graphics[Disk[], Background -> None], 
   ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[gradient]];
d = SetAlphaChannel[gradient, AlphaChannel[diskAlpha]];

LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
 Graphics[{
   Blue, 
   Rectangle[{-.25, -.25}, {1.25, .25}, RoundingRadius -> 0.25],
   White,
   Style[Text["ON", {0.25, 0}], 64, Bold, 
    FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}], 
 {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}},
 Appearance -> ImageResize[d, Scaled[.3]]]
```

[image: attempt]

Comment: nice! but its missing the shadow :-)

Comment: @chris :) and the highlight round the edge, and the black rim, and the shiny reflection, and the text shadow, and many other things besides...! I went to bed instead.

Comment: very smart indeed. I should learn  that trick from you.

Comment: Thanks a lot cormullion! This really is what i was looking for.
I'll post my switch as soon as i'm completely finished.

Comment: Cool. So, are you porting Mathematica to the iPhone‽ :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is the switcher I made using the answer from cormullion. Just one thing: it sort of works, but not quite yet...
After defining the function `SwitcheriOS` twice in one session I get a `Set::setraw` which I cannot repair. I am unable to figure out what is wrong...

But apart from this 'minor' issue it works like a charm!

The code:

```
SwitcheriOS[var_] := Module[{gradient, coord, img, rastimg},
shiny[z_] := GrayLevel[1 - z/4]; 
gradient = 
 Image[DensityPlot[y^2, {x, -.75, .75}, {y, -.25, 25}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> None, ColorFunction -> shiny, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True]];
coord = 
 Block[{n = 100}, 
  Table[{Cos[2 \[Pi] k/n], Sin[2 \[Pi] k/n]}, {k, 0, n - 1}]];
img = Graphics[{Texture@gradient, EdgeForm@None, 
 Polygon[coord, VertexTextureCoordinates -> (coord/2 + .5)], 
  LightGray, Thickness[.05], Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 28, 
  Background -> None];
rastimg = Rasterize[img, RasterSize -> 100, Background -> None];
LocatorPane[Dynamic[var], 
 Graphics[{Dynamic[
    Which[var[[1]] == -.75, Lighter[Gray, .8], var[[1]] == .75, 
     Lighter[Blue, .3]]], 
   Rectangle[{-1.25, -.5}, {1.25, .5}, RoundingRadius -> .5], 
   Dynamic[Which[var[[1]] == -.75, Opacity[.6, White], 
     var[[1]] == .75, Opacity[.2, White]]], 
   Rectangle[{-1, -.5}, {1, 0}, RoundingRadius -> .25], 
   Opacity[.9, White], 
   Dynamic[Text[
     Style[Which[var[[1]] == -.75, "OFF", var[[1]] == .75, "ON"], 
      Which[var[[1]] == -.75, Gray, var[[1]] == .75, White], 13, 
      FontFamily -> "DejaVu Sans", Bold], 
     Which[var[[1]] == -.75, {.5, 0}, var[[1]] == .75, {-.5, 0}]]], 
   EdgeForm[{Lighter[Gray, .3], Thickness[.025]}], Transparent, 
   Rectangle[{-1.25, -.5}, {1.25, .5}, RoundingRadius -> .5]}, 
  ImageSize -> 75], {{-.75, -0}, {.75, -0}, {1.5, 1}}, 
 Appearance -> rastimg]]
```

[image]

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue you mentioned of.

Comment: @PlatoManiac: Thanks for the added image.
I can reproduce the error by calling `SwitcheriOS` with an already defined variable.

Comment: You are welcome! Try to change the borders with some shadow and then you are done 100%.