# How to texturize a polygon?

Tags: graphics, textures

```
pts = {{1.49, 0.33}, {1.51, 0.35}, {1.49, 0.37}, {1.47, 0.39}, {1.41, 
    0.41}, {1.35, 0.43}, {1.29, 0.45}, {1.25, 0.47}, {1.21, 
    0.51}, {1.21, 0.53}, {1.19, 0.57}, {1.17, 0.61}, {1.15, 
    0.67}, {1.13, 0.75}, {1.13, 0.79}, {1.11, 0.85}, {1.19, 
    0.83}, {1.21, 0.81}, {1.29, 0.77}, {1.35, 0.75}, {1.37, 
    0.73}, {1.43, 0.73}, {1.43, 0.71}, {1.49, 0.71}, {1.59, 
    0.73}, {1.67, 0.75}, {1.73, 0.79}, {1.79, 0.81}, {1.83, 
    0.85}, {1.87, 0.89}, {1.89, 0.91}, {1.89, 0.93}, {1.93, 
    0.95}, {1.95, 0.99}, {1.95, 1.01}, {1.99, 1.07}, {2.01, 
    1.15}, {2.01, 1.21}, {2.03, 1.27}, {2.01, 1.33}, {2.01, 
    1.39}, {1.99, 1.47}, {1.97, 1.51}, {1.93, 1.55}, {1.91, 
    1.57}, {1.91, 1.59}, {1.85, 1.65}, {1.85, 1.67}, {1.79, 
    1.71}, {1.77, 1.73}, {1.73, 1.75}, {1.73, 1.77}, {1.67, 
    1.81}, {1.65, 1.83}, {1.63, 1.85}, {1.57, 1.89}, {1.57, 
    1.91}, {1.51, 1.95}, {1.45, 1.99}, {1.45, 2.01}, {1.39, 
    2.05}, {1.39, 2.07}, {1.35, 2.13}, {1.31, 2.17}, {1.29, 
    2.19}, {1.29, 2.21}, {1.25, 2.29}, {1.23, 2.33}, {1.21, 
    2.35}, {1.19, 2.37}, {1.17, 2.45}, {1.15, 2.51}, {1.11, 
    2.59}, {1.11, 2.61}, {1.094, 2.65}, {27/25, 2.71}, {1.066, 
    2.65}, {1.05, 2.63}, {1.03, 2.55}, {1.03, 2.53}, {0.99, 
    2.47}, {0.97, 2.41}, {0.97, 2.39}, {0.91, 2.29}, {0.89, 
    2.25}, {0.89, 2.23}, {0.81, 2.13}, {0.79, 2.09}, {0.75, 
    2.03}, {0.71, 2.01}, {0.69, 1.97}, {0.65, 1.95}, {0.59, 
    1.91}, {0.57, 1.87}, {0.53, 1.85}, {0.47, 1.79}, {0.43, 
    1.77}, {0.35, 1.69}, {0.31, 1.67}, {0.29, 1.63}, {0.27, 
    1.61}, {0.19, 1.51}, {0.17, 1.47}, {0.17, 1.43}, {0.17, 
    1.41}, {0.15, 1.35}, {0.15, 1.29}, {0.15, 1.23}, {0.15, 
    1.17}, {0.15, 1.11}, {0.17, 1.09}, {0.19, 1.03}, {0.23, 
    0.95}, {0.33, 0.85}, {0.37, 0.81}, {0.47, 0.77}, {0.49, 
    0.75}, {0.57, 0.73}, {0.63, 0.71}, {0.69, 0.71}, {0.75, 
    0.71}, {0.77, 0.73}, {0.83, 0.75}, {0.91, 0.79}, {0.95, 
    0.81}, {0.97, 0.83}, {1.05, 0.87}, {1.03, 0.77}, {1.03, 
    0.73}, {1.01, 0.69}, {1.01, 0.63}, {0.97, 0.57}, {0.95, 
    0.53}, {0.93, 0.49}, {0.87, 0.47}, {0.83, 0.45}, {0.77, 
    0.43}, {0.71, 0.41}, {0.69, 0.39}, {0.71, 0.33}, {0.77, 
    0.33}, {0.83, 0.33}, {0.89, 0.33}, {0.95, 0.33}, {1.01, 
    0.33}, {1.07, 0.33}, {1.13, 0.33}, {1.19, 0.33}, {1.25, 
    0.33}, {1.31, 0.33}, {1.37, 0.33}, {1.43, 0.33}};
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2JMe.png"];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{Opacity[0.4], Red, Polygon[pts]}, {Texture[img], 
    Polygon[Map[RotationTransform[tf, {0, 0}], pts], 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> Automatic]}},
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 4, ImageSize -> 300, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic],
 {{tf, 0, "roll"}, 0, -35., -0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

The texture does not completely cover the polygon:
[image: fig1]

After rotating a certain angle, the texture deforms, which is the result I don't want:
[image: fig2]

texture:
[image: fig3]

How does the texture completely cover this polygon and the texture does not deform after rotation ?
Related posts:[How to texturize a Disk/Circle/Rectangle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7661/86487)
`ImageResize`also cannot make the texture completely cover the polygon.It seems that only parametric curves can be completely covered.This problem seems to be related to [conformal mapping](https://mathoverflow.net/q/314189/520896).

Comment: Definition of `p` is missing.

Comment: @DanielHuber The error has been corrected.

Comment: To avoid blurred,maybe use vector graphics format `img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2JMe.png"];
img = ImageGraphics[img, Method -> {"LinearSeparable", 90 \[Degree]}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{Opacity[0.4], Red, Polygon[pts]}, 
   GeometricTransformation[{Texture[img], 
     Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Automatic]}, 
    RotationTransform[tf, {0, 0}]]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 4, 
  ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> Automatic], {{tf, 0, "roll"}, 
  0, -35., -0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2JMe.png"];
ParametricPlot[{-r*Cos[t], -r*(-Sin[t] - Sqrt[Abs[Cos[t]]])}, {r, -1, 
  0}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, Axes -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[img]}, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> True, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: fig1]
This is not the right answer, but I think it is enlightening.