# How to put an imported image in a Disk?

Tags: graphics

The image below contains various ( lightblue filled ) circles ( made with the Disk function ), I want to fill them with an external image ( for example of a face ) such that each circle contains the entire image as if it was cut out in circle shape ( the smaller circles cut out from an image where the size is reduced. )

How can this be done in Mathematica?

EDIT:
Image below now contains the result after the accepted answer has been implemented.

[image: Target image]

Comment: I suggest that including code for your graphic may improve the speed and/or quality of the answers you receive.

Comment: Possible duplicates and/or related: [(1332)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1332/121), [(3723)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3723/121), [(7657)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7657/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard An image in Disk[]//Graphics would suffice. Sadly 1332, 3723, 7657 dont solve the problem. Imagine importing the image of a face. I will edit this in the question. I worked with Textures before which works but I would not know how to do this with Circle or Disk.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I thought about overlaying and transparent colors but I am stuck at that route. I feel like I am missing the obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use your `Disk` (or any grayscale image) as an alpha channel:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "F16"}];

disk = Graphics[Disk[]];

diskImg = 
  ColorConvert[Rasterize[disk, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]], 
   "Grayscale"];

circleImg = ColorCombine[{img, ColorNegate@diskImg}, "RGB"]
```

[image]

Then you can use `Inset` to place it like other graphics primitives:

```
Graphics[{
  Table[
   Inset[circleImg, {Cos[i*10 \[Degree]], 
      Sin[i*10 \[Degree]]}*50, {256, 256}, 5 + i*1], {i, 10}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Everytime I think that I -somewhat- master Mma programming I am blown out by really great programming and new ideas ( for me ) in the answers I receive on this site. - Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`Disk` is less convenient. You can define your own disk as a polygonial approximation (here with a default value of a 50-points polygon):

```
myDisk[n_: 50] := Module[{ps},
   ps = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/n]}]; 
   Polygon[ps, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Rescale[ps]]
   ];
```

**Edit -- changed the picture**

Then everything works:

```
jeb=Import["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Jebcropped.jpg/187px-Jebcropped.jpg"];
Graphics[{Texture[jeb], myDisk[]}]
Graphics[{Texture[jeb], myDisk[3]}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use the new-in-10.1 `CirclePoints`.

Comment: It would have been hilarious if you had used your own gravatar...

Answer (score 2):

This is not really anywhere near a reasonable answer but perhaps it will motivate better answers. I have upvoted the `Texture` approach by use of polygons.

```
img = (* pick your desired graphics*)

g = Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Background -> Black];
Manipulate[
 Row[{ic = ImageCompose[g, img, Scaled[{x, y}]], 
   ia = ImageAdd[ic, 
     msk = Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, r], PlotRange -> Table[{-5, 5}, {2}],
        ImageSize -> {400, 400}]], 
   ImageAdd[ic, 
    Rasterize[
     Plot[x, {x, -5, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
      GridLinesStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
      ImageSize -> {400, 400}, 
      Epilog -> {EdgeForm[{Orange, Thickness[0.02]}], 
        Disk[{0, 0}, r]}]]]}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {r, 0.1, 3}]
```

I just picked a picture of Apollo 11 crew so adapt to whatever image dimensions of graphic and figure that is being overlayed. There are obvious issues with image adding of color images but in the event this can be framed out or as mentioned improved I present.

[image]

Again just an idea that I do not have time (or  expertise) to refine at present  but perhaps OP or others will find helpful.

Comment: I like the Apollo 11 angle, I better not explain why. ;-)

Comment: Not an easy task which answer to give the accept. I upvoted all answers.

Comment: I get the following error message :  "The number of channels must be equal or one of them must be a single-channel image and the other a multichannel image." - Fyi, I use Mma 10 on Windows and am using an image from ExampleData in img.

Comment: @ndroock1 will look at when I get chance...which image?...may be days away

Comment: It is ok. I fixed it otherwise.