# How can I add flags to countries shapes?

Tags: geography

Recently, I wanted to create a map showing the flags of the countries. From the documentation, I found and used the following:

```
flags = EntityValue["Africa", , {"Entity", "Flag"}];

GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[
   Black], {GeoStyling[{"Image", #2}], 
     Tooltip[Polygon[#1], CommonName[#1]]} & @@@ flags}, 
 GeoBackground -> "StreetMapNoLabels"]
```

Then I found :

```
# Show the disembodied shapes of countries in South America:
Row[Show[CountryData[#, "Shape"], ImageSize -> {50, 50}] & /@ CountryData["SouthAmerica"]]
```

Now, I am trying to add the flags and maybe the countries names as captions.

The result should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't work.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1332/10397). Answer also available in documentation for [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
   With[{vc = 
         Transpose[
          Rescale /@ Transpose[First[CountryData[#, "Coordinates"]]]]}, 
       Show[CountryData[#, "Shape"], 
         ImageSize -> {{100}, {100}}] /. {RGBColor[__] :> 
          Texture[ImageReflect[Image[CountryData[#, "Flag"]], 
            Top -> Right]], 
         Polygon[a_] :> 
          Polygon[First[a], VertexTextureCoordinates -> vc]}] & /@ 
     CountryData["SouthAmerica"]
```

**Reference:**

[Texture](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]